# A sufficient condition for convergence of $\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{x_n}{n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The following question arises from checking whether a result is a special case of another one..

**Question:** Let $(x_i)_{i\ge 1}$ be a sequence of positive reals for which 
$$
x_1+\ldots+x_n=o\left(\frac{n^2}{\ln n}\right).
$$
Is it necessarily true that
$$
\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{x_n}{n^2}<\infty?
$$

Comment: At least at first glance it seems highly unlikely - if $x_n\approx \frac{n}{\ln n \ln\ln n}$ then it looks like you should get the first result but then the sum goes as $\sum_n (n\ln n \ln\ln n)^{-1}$, which is divergent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fleshing out my comment into an answer: if you take $x_n\approx \dfrac{n}{\ln n\ln\ln n}$, then $\sum_{i\leq n} x_i\lt nx_n$ $=\dfrac{n^2}{\ln n\ln\ln n}$ $\in o\left(\dfrac{n^2}{\ln n}\right)$, but $\sum_n \dfrac{x_n}{n^2}=\sum_n(n\ln n\ln\ln n)^{-1}$diverges by classical results.

Comment: Well done, thank you :)